# Getting map but without json data

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview, android-parser

Not Getting JSON data into mapview to show locations, but getting blank map,
I am making a program in which I am trying to fetch json data into mapview, but whenever I run my app getting map without JSON data, so please see what is the problem and what are the changes I need to do, here I am placing my code, please see:-

```
public class MapView extends MapActivity {

public GeoPoint point;
TapControlledMapView mapView; // use the custom TapControlledMapView
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
Drawable drawable;
SimpleItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

    mapView = (TapControlledMapView) findViewById(R.id.viewmap);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);

//   new DownloadWebPageTask().execute();


    // dismiss balloon upon single tap of MapView (iOS behavior) 
    mapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {      


        public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            itemizedOverlay.hideAllBalloons();
            return true;

        }
    });

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();        
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    itemizedOverlay = new SimpleItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);         
    itemizedOverlay.setShowClose(false);
    itemizedOverlay.setShowDisclosure(true);
    itemizedOverlay.setSnapToCenter(false);



    class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // Perform a GET request for a JSON list
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://dl.***.com/maps.json");
            // Get the response that sends back
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = client.execute(request);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Convert this response into a readable string
            String jsonString = null;
            try {
                jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Create a JSON object that we can use from the String
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("maps");
                Log.e("log_tag", "Opening JSON Array ");
                for(int i=0;i < jsonArray.length();i++){                      
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String latitude =  jsonObject.getString("latitude");
                    String longitude =  jsonObject.getString("longitude");
                    String title =  jsonObject.getString("title");
                    String country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                    Log.e("log_tag", "ADDING GEOPOINT"+title); 
                    point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
                    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem
                        (point, title, country);
                    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
               }
           }catch(JSONException e)        {
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
           } 


           return jsonString;
       }

           @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    itemizedOverlay.populateNow(); 

           mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
           if (savedInstanceState == null) {
               MapController controller = mapView.getController();
               controller.setCenter(point);
               controller.setZoom(7);
           } else {
               // example restoring focused state of overlays
               int focused;
               focused = savedInstanceState.getInt("focused_1", -1);
               if (focused >= 0) {
                   itemizedOverlay.setFocus(itemizedOverlay.getItem(focused));
               }
           }
              }

    }

    }
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

    }
```

**JSON Data**

```
{
"maps": [
{

"title": "Place One",
"latitude" : "46.483742",
"longitude" : "7.663157",
"country": "Switzerland"
},
{
"title" : "Place Two",
"latitude" : "59.25235",
"longitude" : "18.465536",
"country" : "Sweden"
},
{
"title" : "Place Three",
"latitude" : "56.404182",
"longitude" : "-3.818855",
"country" : "Scotland"
}
]
}
```

Comment: ur map is being display or not ?

Comment: able to view map, but not locations in short not getting json data

Comment: @Stanley you solved your AsyncTask qestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are getting SimpleItemizedOverlay, but I'm assuming it is a custom implementation extending ItemizedOverlay. If so, could you please provide that source as well?

Without the SimpleItemizedOverlay source my suggestions would be:

- Verify you are calling `populate()` on your `itemizedOverlay` within it's constructor.
- Move `mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);` into your `onCreate` method immediately after `itemizedOverlay` is instantiated. In it's current position the overlay is re-added on subsequent ASyncTask runs.
- Within `onPostExecute` call `itemizedOverlay.populate()` and then `mapView.postInvalidate()` to force a refresh

Otherwise I would add debug messages to SimpleItemizedOverlay to verify the JSON data is being added correctly, but without that source I can't provide an example.